# Suspend system instead of shutdown on CPU overheat

Tags: cpu, cpu-frequency

I have  Linux Mint. The system Linux Mint is installed on, shuts down immediately on overheating.

Is there anyway the system doesn't shutdown, but goes to standby state?

The machine can always be super optimized so it never heats up, but I think if Linux can shut it down, then can't it suspend it? There must be some way.

Comment: I would advise you to try to focus on the causes and not the symptoms. Tracking down processes writing to disk, some mis-behaved wifi card, getting a fan, reapplying thermal paste, or opening parts of the case could be all  actions to take, depending on the equipment and the problem.

Comment: I convert videos using VLC. For longer videos, it sucks up all of the CPU upto 400%. and enventually shuts down.

Comment: Rui is correct, a properly-cooled system should be able to run at full tilt indefinitely without overheating.

Comment: Thanks, but I think if Linux can shut it down, then it can suspend it as well. Why not then?

Comment: Is you system shutting down with a "critical temperature reached(XX C),shutting down" message?

Comment: No idea, how do I check it?

Comment: You may find that it's the firmware that's shutting it down.  Do you have options in your BIOS/UEFI for over temp shutdown?  If you disable those, then make sure you have an alternative within your Linux distro to manage your temperature for you.